# Docker - Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache

Tags: docker, dns, dockerfile

I am using a Dockerfile to hit our corporate Nexus (npm) server for 'npm install' commands. I am seeing:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 216.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* connect to 216.xxx.xxx.xxx port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to nexus.<something>.com port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to nexus.<something>.com port 443:     Connection refused
```

I can resolve www.google.com. I can hit and and use our corporate NPM registery from my local box. It appears that only our internal dns names are the problem and only when attempting to access them from inside a docker container. I've googled and not been able to determine the changes I need to make to fix this problem.

Dockerfile (I've trimmed the irrelevant commands):

```
FROM node:6.3
RUN curl -k -v https://www.google.com
RUN curl -k -vv https://nexus.<something>.com/repository/npm-all/
```

The curl to google.com succeeds. The curl to our internal repo fails.

I am starting it with the command:

```
docker build .
```

Contents of /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#    DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

I am running Ubuntu 15.10.

### Solution

@BMitch is correct. Modify the contents of /etc/resolv.conf by adding dns server addresses associated with your corporate network. In the case of Ubuntu 15+ (i am running gnome3) your config file will be overwritten by the Network Manager so it cannot be hand edited. Make the changes via the Network Manager gui. Open Network Settings, select the DNS tab and add servers.

Comment: Can you show your /etc/resolv.conf of your Docker host?

Comment: Added to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local dns address is the issue you're facing. The container can't connect to your localhost ip from inside the container. The solution is to pass an ip address of the DNS server in your `docker run` or update your /etc/resolv.conf to point to a non-loopback ip address.

From [Docker's DNS documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/):

> Filtering is necessary because all localhost addresses on the host are
>   unreachable from the container’s network. After this filtering, if
>   there are no more nameserver entries left in the container’s
>   /etc/resolv.conf file, the daemon adds public Google DNS nameservers
>   (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) to the container’s DNS configuration. If IPv6 is
>   enabled on the daemon, the public IPv6 Google DNS nameservers will
>   also be added (2001:4860:4860::8888 and 2001:4860:4860::8844).
>
> > Note: If you need access to a host’s localhost resolver, you must modify your DNS service on the host to listen on a non-localhost
> >     address that is reachable from within the container.